# How can i anchor points on my .docx template file to dump my variable strings?

Tags: python-3.x, docx

I am trying to find the right approach to insert text that is stored in variables in to a docx template file stored in the same directory as my app for gathering the data strings.

I looked at abusing the mail merge work arounds in word but that seems to be a lot more locked down in later versions of office...i have 365.

the python.docx module seems clunky for what i need using runs etc...

How can i anchor points on the template to dump my variable strings?

i might add that the template has a lot of borders and boxes around each section and spans 2 pages.

would it be easier to do if my doc was a pdf?

what other file format would be a better match for what i want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a tutorial posted by Chris Moffitt that uses lxml package to use a form of mail merge with word templates.

https://pbpython.com/python-word-template.html

This is exactly what i was after. It uses "quick parts" to form an anchor in the word template so that i can replace them later using python code in sections of my document.